# Stretch 3 bands of many false color images at the same time

Tags: qgis

I have many 3-band false color images, I would like to stretch band 1, band 2 and band 3 to the maximum and minimum values ​​of the set for all images at the same time before creating the virtual image on which to obtain NDVI. Wrong? Simple? I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Stretching the bands before calculating the NDVI will not alter the NDVI results so you can just calculate it as is.

Comment: thanks, yes I know, it's a fraction. However, using NDVI I cannot distinguish conifers from some types of vegetation, so I would like to use the third band to try to distinguish them, because the coloration of the conifers in the false color image is different from the vegetation with which it shares the same NDVI. However, it is true that I could multiply or divide the NDVI value by the third band without stretching all the bands. Right ?

Comment: I have no idea what bands you are using so I have no idea if it will do what you want it to do. If you are asking 'CAN bands be divided or multiplied?'. The answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks again. It would be useful to know if there is a way to stretch each individual band to a maximum and minimum value but for all images at the same time. Bye